# Codeless Android BLE Characteristic always returns same value

Tags: java, android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I perform a simple write command

```
    atWriteCharacteristic.setWriteType(BluetoothGattCharacteristic.WRITE_TYPE_DEFAULT);
    atWriteCharacteristic.setValue("ATI"); // no matter what value I put here always same response
    boolean didWrite = bluetoothGatt.writeCharacteristic(atWriteCharacteristic);
```

But when I attempt to read via:

```
    bluetoothGatt.readCharacteristic(atReadCharacteristic);
```

I always get the same response of "OK" which is incorrect and should be giving me an application version instead. I get response in the onCharacteristicRead call back function.
Here is a link to the codeless application:
http://lpccs-docs.dialog-semiconductor.com/UM-140-DA145x-CodeLess/howToUse.html#software-setup

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have resolved this. The problem was much simpler. It was me not sending the space after each "AT" command. So the commands need to be specifically in this format: "AT "
with the space after each one.